# Keil's uVision: debugging and viewing RAM memory

Tags: debugging, keil

I am using Keil's uVision development environment to develop for the DS89C450 (8052) chip. I want to use a memory view to be able to view the RAM, specifically the stack. However, when I open a memory view I am only seeing the flash memory (0x0000 - 0xFFFF). How can I view the data in the RAM memory?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 1):

Someone in my class figured this out soon after posting the question. In order to view a certain type of memory, you need to proceed the address you are looking up with the letter associated with the memory map you want to view. In other words in uVision for the DS89C450 chip the following memory maps are defined:

001 I:0x00 - 0xFF read write
002 C:0x0000 - 0x0002 exec read
003 C:0x0800 - 0x081F exec read
004 X:0x000000 - 0x00FFFF read write

The RAM memory in the first entry so when entering an address (like 0x07, the initial value of the SP) to look up in that memory map proceed the address with I: to get I:0x07. The memory viewer knows now what memory you are requesting to look up.